# why is thrown this exception: cannot create signer: no such algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA for provider SunPKCS11?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, sign, pkcs#11

This exception was thrown when i was trying to sign with a PKCS11. I tried changing the case of letters thinking that it could be the problem but it wasn´t.

Answer (score 1):

The real cause of this problem doesn´t correspond to the message of the exception in my case, in wich i then realized that it was just that the PKCS11 token was disconnected. If some day this happens to you, make sure to have a token connected. When you remove the token and try to sign, it throws the exception: Token was removed, but when you repeat the proccess that is the exception it throws.
I hope this help someone like me!

Comment: Thank you for including the information that resolved the problem.